# Uncaught lua exception error in zerobrane, any solution?

Tags: lua, rgb, zerobrane

Zerobrane version `v1.90`

This error is caused after I put the following code into user preference:

```
styles.indicator.fncall = {fg = {-110,0,0}} --I got this in documentation page of zerobrane
```

I tried to reinstall zerobrane(both portable version and .exe verison) but the problem is still here.

Screenshot of the error message:

[image: Zerobrane-error.png]

Comment: Have you even read the error message? `Expected an 'unsigned integer' for parameter 1`

Comment: How should negative color look like?

Answer (score 1):

```lua
{-110,0,0}
```

You're passing a negative value as the red value; there's no way that could work (What would it even do?)

Comment: uh, this question is about the solution of the problem, not the cause

Comment: And I gave you the solution, didn't I? You can't use a negative number for the colour.